# extract data from sql query json format

Tags: sql, metabase

I have a table sensor_measurements and the columns measurements and measure_at (timestamp)

```
 select measured_at, pollutants
    from sensor_measurements;
```

which gives:

```
October 22, 2019, 9:00 PM
[{"name": "NO", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.002161, "temporal_resolution": "1h"},
 {"name": "NO2", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.002, "temporal_resolution": "1h"},
  {"name": "TEMP", "units": "celsius", "concentration": 28, "temporal_resolution": "1h"},
   {"name": "HUM", "units": "percent", "concentration": 38, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
   {"name": "PM10", "units": "µg/m3", "concentration": 8, "temporal_resolution": "1h"},
    {"name": "PM25", "units": "µg/m3", "concentration": 7, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}]
    
October 22, 2019, 10:00 PM
[{"name": "NO", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.002205, "temporal_resolution": "1h"},
 {"name": "NO2", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.008, "temporal_resolution": "1h"},
  {"name": "TEMP", "units": "celsius", "concentration": 28, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
  {"name": "HUM", "units": "percent", "concentration": 38, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
  {"name": "PM10", "units": "µg/m3", "concentration": 9, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
  {"name": "PM25", "units": "µg/m3", "concentration": 8, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}]
  
October 22, 2019, 11:00 PM
[{"name": "NO", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.002209, "temporal_resolution": "1h"},
 {"name": "NO2", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.004, "temporal_resolution": "1h"},
  {"name": "TEMP", "units": "celsius", "concentration": 28, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
  {"name": "HUM", "units": "percent", "concentration": 38, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
  {"name": "PM10", "units": "µg/m3", "concentration": 8, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
  {"name": "PM25", "units": "µg/m3", "concentration": 7, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}]
  
October 23, 2019, 12:00 AM
[{"name": "NO", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.002125, "temporal_resolution": "1h"},
{"name": "NO2", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.004, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
{"name": "TEMP", "units": "celsius", "concentration": 28, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
{"name": "HUM", "units": "percent", "concentration": 39, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}]


October 23, 2019, 4:00 PM
[{"name": "NO", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.004563, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
{"name": "TEMP", "units": "celsius", "concentration": 34, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
{"name": "HUM", "units": "percent", "concentration": 28, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}]
```

I want to extract the timestamp, `pollutant` and it's value (concentration!

Ideally , I want to create three columns with timestamp, pollutant and value in order to download as csv.

The database type is PostgreSQl (in metabase.com)

Comment: Please provide Sql Engine

Comment: @LeszekMazur:It;s in metabase.com

Comment: Is your metabase suite underpinned with a RDBMs of any sort ?  Are you able to gain access to the data via the underpinned SQL database -  https://www.metabase.com/learn/data-diet/analytics/which-data-warehouse.html

Comment: Am able to parse if a properly formed json structure is generated - sample 
echo ' {"measured_at": "October 23, 2019, 12:00 AM",
"lines": [ 
{"name": "NO", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.002125, "temporal_resolution": "1h"},
{"name": "NO2", "units": "ppm", "concentration": 0.004, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
{"name": "TEMP", "units": "celsius", "concentration": 28, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}, 
{"name": "HUM", "units": "percent", "concentration": 39, "temporal_resolution": "1h"}]}
' | jq

Comment: @irnerd:It uses postgresql

Comment: Thanks @George - I'd recommend using a different client kit and connection to retrievec your extract - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients  - there are a number of good clients out there. Tora, AquaData Studio are well known and supported , to start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it on postgres.
First of all you have to have type represents your data:

```sql
CREATE TYPE x as ("name" VARCHAR , "units" VARCHAR , "concentration" FLOAT, "temporal_resolution" VARCHAR );
```

Next, you can use json as joined table:

```sql
SELECT measured_at, name, concentration
FROM sensor_measurements
LEFT JOIN LATERAL json_populate_recordset(null::x, pollutants::json) ON true;
```

Comment: Hi, it seems good, just that I cannot execute `create type` through metabase `ERROR: cannot execute CREATE TYPE in a read-only transaction`. I have admin permissions though.

Comment: So try to do it outside the transaction - it is one time, so you do it once, and you can get results every time in transaction